# How to capture Stored Procedure call using DMV or jobs in sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

Hi i am working on SQL Server 2008 R2, can somebody help me to collect actual stored procedure call and estimated time it took to execute that SP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SQL Profiler events or Extendent Events.
For profiler you use:
- SP prefix events and RPC prefix events
For extendent events you use sp prefix events

http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2011/10/sql-server-using-sql-profiler-to.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630354(v=sql.105).aspx